# What does interpolation mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is a simple Ruby code, but I am not getting how to understand and use it.

```
def string_length_interpolater(incoming_string)
  "The string you just gave me has a length of #{incoming_string.length}"
end
```

Could somebody help me the process?

Comment: `string_length_interpolated "sample string"` or `puts string_length_interpolated("sample string")` if you want to display the result.

Comment: @nameless an example could help me very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns a string with the phrase shown ("The string you...") plus the length of the string passed in, e.g.

```
string_length_interpolater('Hi')

=>  "The string you just gave me has a length of 2" 

string_length_interpolater('Hi There')

=>  "The string you just gave me has a length of 8" 

string_length_interpolater('123456789')

=>  "The string you just gave me has a length of 9" 

string_length_interpolater('Hello Ruby')

=>  "The string you just gave me has a length of 10"
```

As you can see the method is just returning that text - "The string you just gave me has a length" with the length of the parameter that is passed in.  The `#{}` within the DOUBLE quotes means work out the ruby value and then use that in the string.

It is also the same as

```
def string_length_interpolater(incoming_string)
  "The string you just gave me has a length of " + incoming_string.length
end
```

When the output becomes comples - a string with 'ruby output at various points it becomes easier to use the doubles qoutes ('interpolation') method, for example this:

```
"From #{start} to #{end} the #{person} used a #{tool}"
```

is often easier to read/write/maintain than

```
"From " + start + " to " + end + " the " + person + " used a " + tool
```

Added:  If you ALSO want to show the value of the string itself you could use:

```
def string_and_length(nm)
  "Hello there #{nm}, did you know your name is #{nm.length} letters long?"
end
```

Comment: You define the function once with the def name... end  After that you call it with a string between the parentheses.  The function simply returns the text and the length of the string passed in.  __Perhaps__ you want the string too.  Let me add that example.